# Grub configuration won't take updates to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

Tags: debian, grub2

I'm trying to set up kdump on a Debian Buster system, following [this article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/oops-debugging-kernel-panics-0).

I've installed the `kdump-tools` package which created `/etc/default/grub.d/kdump-tools.cfg`, which performs this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT crashkernel=384M-:128M"
```

My understanding is that this will append the `crashkernel` argument to the kernel command line parameters.

I run `sudo update-grub`, which appears to succeed, but the word `crashkernel` doesn't appear in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (or anywhere under `/boot` for that matter).

The generated `grub.cfg` has this:

```
menuentry "Linux" --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-b05e794c-10ea-4c8b-8ee4-2d51c8875d85' {
    ...
    echo    'Loading Linux 5.9.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.9.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 root=UUID=b05e794c-10ea-4c8b-8ee4-2d51c8875d85 ro  quiet processor.max_cstate=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=1
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.9.0-0.bpo.5-amd64
}
```

I've confirmed that the other files in `/etc/defaults/grub.d` are not modifying `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. I've tried adding `crashkernel` directly to `/etc/default/grub`. I've also confirmed with strace that `/etc/default/grub.d/kdump-tools.cfg` is being read.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure, but I notice that `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux` creates entries like this, where `${args}` is `${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}`.

```
linux   ${rel_dirname}/${basename} root=${linux_root_device_thisversion} ro ${args}
```

However, I found an `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/custom` which includes the `linux` line that ends up in my `grub.cfg`, which does *not* include `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.9.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 root=UUID=b05e794c-10ea-4c8b-8ee4-2d51c8875d85 ro  quiet processor.max_cstate=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=1
```

I manually added `crashkernel` to it, and that seemed to work.

Possibly this was made overly complicated by someone running GRUB Customizer.